# Inserting a string into another one, every N characters

Tags: php, string

Say we have the string `$string="lolololol|lolololol|lolololol|lolololol"`. As I need to display it in the browser, I want to add a `<wbr>` tag ([see](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html))  every N (say, 50) characters, but I'm not sure of how to do it in PHP. I saw some solutions in other languages using regex, but I don't actually know how to use it, so I'd prefer other solutions.

Comment: all those `lolo` simply MUST have a `tro` prepended...

Comment: @MarcB That was just placeholder, without-spaces text to make an example, with an implicit link to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6LzEbuI7e8) xD

Comment: @Mr.Alien ? Once I know the length of the string, I still need to place the string and know where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use wordwrap for that

```
<?php
$string="lolololol|lolololol|lolololol|lolololol";
echo wordwrap( $string, 50, "<wbr>", true);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc11fedb6f1d1f76e2c869826f5a8f6a344c41b9)

Comment: Fits exactly to my needs, thanks. (Just couldn't find the function on [PHP.net](php.net) :| )

Answer (score 0):

```
$string="lolololol|lolololol|lolololol|lolololol";
echo chunk_split($string, 7,"TRO");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby answer:

```
def put_wbr str, sub_str, num
  new_str = ""
  str.each_char{ |s| new_str.length % num == 0 ? new_str += sub_str : new_str += s }
  new_str[4..-1]
end
```